# 9-Patch with two strechable regions

Tags: android, nine-patch

Is it possible to have a 9-Patch with two (or multiple) strechable regions / areas?

If its possible,
how do I specify that the first area will strech 70 percent and the second 30 percent?
or 50 percent and 50 percent?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have multiple strechable regions in your 9patch. But i don't know for the percent thing, I hope you'll get an answer on this, it's interesting to me too :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have a 9-Patch with two (or multiple) strechable
>   regions / areas?

Yes

> If its possible, how do I specify that the first area will strech 70
>   percent and the second 30 percent? or 50 percent and 50 percent?

I don't think this is possible.

I know you can specify multiple stretch zone like

```
    X       X
  ************
X ************
  ************
  ****LOGO****
  ************
X ************
  ************
```

Comment: just use 3 black pixels in the first region and 7 ones in the second

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit? The code block is for code, if you are quoting the question that use the quote block. It looks stupid with syntax highlight and a scroll bar!

Comment: So 3 black pixels = 30 % and 7 pixels = 70 %. Sounds good. Im going to test it.